# Negative Binomial dispersion parameter in SPSS

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss, negative-binomial-distribution, overdispersion

I am working in accident prediction modeling and I'm using SPSS Generalized Linear Model procedure with **Negative Binomial** distribution and **Log Link Function**.

Does anyone know the form in wich SPSS returns the **dispersion parameter**?
Is it the form `Var(x)=mu+dispersion*mu^2`?
All i know is that the dispersion parameter is equal to 0 for a Poisson distribution, where `Var(x)=mu`.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have the form right, specifically the variance for the $j$th observation is:

$$\text{Var}(x_j) = \mu_j(1 + au_j)$$

Stata and SPSS have the same defaults, so I will refer to [Stata's documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnbreg.pdf) (see page 5) for a nice walkthrough. This is the NB2 model from Cameron and Trivedi (which I have not read, but is cited as such in the Long and Freese *Regression Models for Categorical Dependent Variables Using Stata*).

It can be tricky when reading texts. Sometimes people refer to the *dispersion* as the entire thing in the parentheses (which changes per the mean estimate of the variable), but other times they only refer to $a$ (which is what the software reports). I've written a [blog post translating](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/translating-between-the-dispersion-term-in-a-negative-binomial-regression-and-random-variables-in-spss/) between a few of the regularly used notations for negative binomial parameterizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate dispersion parameter by this address 
Analyze/Generalized linear Models/custom/select negative binomial distribution/link function =log/ then in estimation tab in scale parameter method select Fixed value
if u run, you'll see overdispersion parameter in parameters estimation table.its value is next to the negative binomial

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know which form of the parameter not how to access it. See the accepted answer.