# Gradient Descent negative binomial (but generally multiple-parameter families)

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression, poisson-regression

Say I'm doing a negative binomial regression and I'm trying to fit my model via gradient descent.

[image]

Given that the Poisson and Negative Binomial have the same inverse link, how might I account for the dispersion?

P.s I need to implement this via GD as I'm working with encrypted ML; I can't do inverses or transposes easily within my problem setup

Comment: Stata docs have a likelihood function https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnbreg.pdf (pg 11) -- although not 100% sure if the NB2 variant of the dispersion term is the same as your screenshot. Note for max-lik people typically fix the dispersion term (or do a grid search). I've just feed it in as a [parameter for back-propagation](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2020/11/10/a-latent-variable-approach-to-rtm-using-hidden-layers-in-deep-learning/) though in the past and have had fine results.

Comment: That's super cool! Mind converting this into a full answer? I'm more than happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like looking at the Stata docs when I am implementing these models loss functions in other guises. So [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnbreg.pdf) on pg 11 Stata has a likelihood function for their version of negative binomial regression.

[image: ll for nbreg]

Where $\alpha$ is the dispersion estimate and $u_j$ is the mean estimate (same as for Poisson regression). This is a variant called the [NB2 distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200351/1036). I have an example on my [blog of using this as a loss function in a pytorch deep learning model](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2020/11/10/a-latent-variable-approach-to-rtm-using-hidden-layers-in-deep-learning/). So here is the code for torch tensors, but should be easily translatable to other coding languages:

```
# pytorch loss function
def nb2_loss(actual, log_pred, disp):
    m = 1/disp.exp()
    mu = log_pred.exp()
    p = 1/(1 + disp.exp()*mu)
    nll = torch.lgamma(m + actual) - torch.lgamma(actual+1) - torch.lgamma(m)
    nll += m*torch.log(p) + actual*torch.log(1-p)
    return -nll.mean()
```

Just a few notes -- I paramaterize $\log(\alpha)$ as `disp` in this loss function. So this constrains the $\alpha$ parameter to always be positive. Like all models that use backpropogation, you need decent starting parameters. I think a starting parameter of somewhere between 0 and 1 works well for the problems I have dealt with.

For a second note, I have had terrible time with using pytorch's stochastic gradient descent in all my experiments with this (even with Poisson regression and fake data so I know good starting points). So at this point I always just default to the Adam optimizer (but again good starting points for all parameters are important).

Comment: I tried doing this but get some unfortunate (but understandable) learning dynamics. The initial regression coefficient estimates are bad, so alpha gets small (~= high noise variance), then eventually the regression coefficients get better which drives alpha higher (~= low noise variance). So your "good starting point" comment is very true.